# tailwind v3, How to use arbitrary color value in php echo?

Tags: php, css

"#1FFFC6" and "#4C59FF" are custom colors picked from some color picker in wordpress backend.

if i write the code below directly, it works just fine.

```
<h1 class="bg-[#1FFFC6] text-[#4C59FF]"> h1 title </h1>
```

but, this one not working.

```
$nav_bgcolor = "#1FFFC6";
$nav_textcolor = "#4C59FF";
echo "<h1 class='bg-[$nav_bgcolor] text-[$nav_textcolor]'>title</h1>";
```

is there any way i can do this by using tailwind and php echo?
please help, thanks.

env :
php7.4, tailwind v3, vscode.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a space between `h1` and `class`.

```
echo "<h1 class='bg-[$nav_bgcolor] text-[$nav_textcolor]'>title</h1>";
```

Comment: I miss a  space when I white this post, thanks for you reply, but  It's not the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In your file: tailwind.config.js you need to add mode: 'jit'.

source: https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode
e.g:

```
module.exports = {  
   mode: 'jit',  
   content: [
        './*.php',
        ......
    ],
    //other options
}
```

Comment: This won't solve the problem. Tailwind isn't able to parse through the variables and determine what to generate, unless it's a [full class name](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#classes-aren-t-generated). I don't believe the OP's problem is readily solvable by Tailwind, though [solutions using CSS variables like this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72328467/1449223) might be a workable compromise.