# Load colors for tailwind.config.js from server database by using PHP

Tags: php, tailwind-css

We are using a extension which uses tailwind.

We have multiple shops which needs this extension. Each shop has different colors.

We would like to load the color from the shops database into tailwind, because our lead developer does not want us to use multiple git branches for each project.

This is my *tailwind.config.js*:

```
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')

module.exports = {
  prefix: 'hfc-',
  important: true,
  purge: ['./view/frontend/**/*.ts', './view/frontend/**/*.vue'],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    colors: {
      transparent: 'transparent',
      white: colors.white,
      gray: colors.gray,
      red: colors.red,
      primary: {
        DEFAULT: '#EB7B2D',
        50: '#FFFFFF',
        100: '#FDF0E7',
        200: '#F8D3B9',
        300: '#F4B68A',
        400: '#EF985C',
        500: '#EB7B2D',
        600: '#D16214',
        700: '#A34C0F',
        800: '#74360B',
        900: '#452007',
      },
      green: {
        DEFAULT: '#52AE32',
        50: '#DBF2D3',
        100: '#CBEDBF',
        200: '#ABE198',
        300: '#8AD670',
        400: '#6ACB48',
        500: '#52AE32',
        600: '#3F8627',
        700: '#2D5F1B',
        800: '#1A3710',
        900: '#071004',
      },
    },
    fontSize: {
      sm: ['12px', '16px'],
      base: ['14px', '20px'],
      lg: ['16px', '24px'],
      xl: ['20px', '28px'],
      '2xl': ['28px', '36px'],
      '3xl': ['36px', '44px'],
      '4xl': ['44px', '52px'],
      '5xl': ['52px', '60px'],
    },
    fontFamily: {
      sans: 'Open Sans',
      serif: 'Montserrat',
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

How can I load the colors from the server by using PHP ?

Comment: This seems to be a limitation of tailwind and is not possible, so it looks like we need to either solve it with another technology or use different git branches

Comment: What does database return? Is it color string like `primary`, `green` or an array of HEX colors, or something else?

Comment: It just returns a single `string` (varchar or text). One per color position.

Comment: You may set custom [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) something like `:root {--hfc-green-100: <?php echo $color; ?>;}`, where $color - is sanitized HEX from database (with default callback if no value was set), and within Tailwind config set color as `var(--hfc-green-100)` (instead of hardcoded `#CBEDBF`)

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka, thats a good idea, i will try this out today, thx! :)

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka, that worked, thank you! Can you create an answer so I can accept it? I will also edit it to add more infos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case where database returns single string for every color position, you may set [CSS variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)

```css
:root {
  --hfc-green-100: <?php echo $color; ?>;
}
```

where `$color` - sanitized color from database (with default value if not present)

Now you can change `tailwind.config.js` - instead of hardcoded colors use this variables

```js
// Showing only related part
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    colors: {
      green: {,
        100: 'var(--hfc-green-100)',
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: this is what we need, color themes from either backend config or from saved from db.