# Tailwind dynamic theme configuration for react

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui, tailwind-in-js

Is there any way to configure the theme values dynamically in tailwind react ?
I am getting my theme values (background color, color) from server.
I need to update these values in tailwind config and use.
Not able to find anything in their documentation
Example:
I am getting primary color as #bada55 from server
I need to update this value in tailwind config.

Any workaround would also be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Use CSS [variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72300855/load-colors-for-tailwind-config-js-from-server-database-by-using-php/72328467#72328467) instead of hard-coded colors

Comment: Ya, used css variables only and referenced those var in tailwind.config.js
Thanks