# How can I have dynamic 'primary' classes in TailwindCSS?

Tags: javascript, css, tailwind-css

I need to have a dynamic theme for my website that comes from a database, possible values are `theme-1`, `theme-2` etc. and I want each one to change the color palette of the site, i.e the `primary` tailwind color being `green` for `theme-1` but `blue` for `theme-2`.

I have tried using https://github.com/upupming/tailwindcss-themeable but it is such an overkill as it regenerates all the colors and has a very cumbersome and long prefix before each class. I want to define the 'theme-1' class at the `body` level and do something along the lines of this pseudo code

```
.theme-2 {
  /* primary-500 is now color: blue */
}
```

I am using Tailwind v2 due to dependency constraints.

Comment: How much colors do you have in a single palette? Maybe, using CSS [variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72300855/load-colors-for-tailwind-config-js-from-server-database-by-using-php/72328467#72328467) is solution here, but it depends

Comment: I'll generate a few palettes using https://www.tailwindshades.com. The important thing for me is to be able to reuse primary as a class name and have tailwind classes like bg-primary-500 and text-primary-500 automatically switch, as there will be a lot of HTML generated with Vue

Comment: Having a look at https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#using-css-variables:~:text=Define%20your%20CSS%20variables%20as%20channels%20with%20no%20color%20space%20function thanks to your suggestion. However it seems this is only a solution for multiple classes, and not dynamically overwriting 'primary' as I'm hoping

Comment: You may create custom components fro every theme, but not entirely sure it is a good idea. Like DO NOT create pallete named `primary`, but a bunch of others. And define components in CSS like `.theme-1 .text-primary-500 {@apply text-theme1-500}, .theme-2 .text-primary-500 {@apply text-theme2-500}` and so on. Another solution is to write custom variant for every theme maybe. Use it like `theme1:text-green-500 theme2:text-blue-500` but again it hard to maintain for a big amount of themes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: use CSS Variables.

main.css

```
:root .theme-1 {
        --tw-text-opacity: 1;
        --color-primary-50: 235,242,254;
        --color-primary-100: 215,230,253;
        --color-primary-200: 176,205,251;
        --color-primary-300: 137,180,250;
        --color-primary-400: 98,155,248;
        --color-primary-500: 59,130,246;
        --color-primary-600: 11,97,238;
        --color-primary-700: 8,75,184;
        --color-primary-800: 6,53,131;
        --color-primary-900: 4,31,77;
    }
```

tailwind.config.js

```
colors: {
    ...
    primary: {
        50: 'rgba(var(--color-primary-50), var(--tw-text-opacity))',
        100:'rgba(var(--color-primary-100), var(--tw-text-opacity))',
        200:'rgba(var(--color-primary-200), var(--tw-text-opacity))',
        300:'rgba(var(--color-primary-300), var(--tw-text-opacity))',
        400:'rgba(var(--color-primary-400), var(--tw-text-opacity))',
        500:'rgba(var(--color-primary-500), var(--tw-text-opacity))',
        600:'rgba(var(--color-primary-600), var(--tw-text-opacity))',
        700:'rgba(var(--color-primary-700), var(--tw-text-opacity))',
        800:'rgba(var(--color-primary-800), var(--tw-text-opacity))',
        900:'rgba(var(--color-primary-900), var(--tw-text-opacity))'
    }

...
```

Now you can use text-primary-500 and have the color change with only 1 parent class

Comment: You can also keep all CSS configuration co-located in a single tailwind config file by [defining themes in custom plugins](https://www.oliverdavies.uk/archive/2022/09/11/custom-styles-tailwind-css-apply-theme-custom-plugins)

Answer (score 3):

You might use [tw-colors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tw-colors). It is a slim plugin that makes it really easy to configure multiple color themes.

*tailwind.config.js*

```js
const { createThemes } = require('tw-colors');

   module.exports = {
      content: ['./src/**/*.{astro,html,js,jsx,md,mdx,svelte,ts,tsx,vue}'],
      plugins: [
         createThemes({
            halloween: { 
               'primary': 'orange',
               'secondary': 'yellow',
            },
            summer: { 
               'primary': 'pink',
               'secondary': 'red',
            },
            winter: { 
               'primary': 'blue',
               'secondary': 'green',
            },
            party: { 
               'primary': 'steelblue',
               'secondary': 'darkblue',
            },
         })
      ],
   };
```

use themes like this with class:

```html
<html class='theme-halloween'>
      ...
</html>
```

Or with data attributes:

```html
<html data-theme='halloween'>
      ...
</html>
```

Themes can be switched dynamically with some toggle button or whatever you prefer